# Custom Validation Function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to understand how handlers work with validation in Google's UI Service.

If I have a text box with a button and I only want to contact the server if the text box is 1) Not Empty and 2) Contains a specific value, for e.g. 'Fred' how do I create a validation function that checks if the value is 'Fred' before allowing the serverhandler to fire?

Some example code:

```
function myValid() {

 //create the app
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();

 //set out UI in table
 var flex = app.createFlexTable()
  .setWidget(0, 0, app.createTextBox().setName('textbox').setId('textbox'))
  .setWidget(0, 1, app.createButton('Submit').setId('submit'))
  .setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel().setId('status'));

 //server handler - fires only if textbox isn't empty
 var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('submit')
  .validateLength(app.getElementById('textbox'), 1, null)
  .addCallbackElement(flex);

 //my custom handler to check the value of the textbox
 var myserverHandler = app.createServerHandler('myCheck')
 .addCallbackElement(flex);

 //client handler to display a message if textbox is empty
 var clientHandler = app.createClientHandler()
 .validateNotLength(app.getElementById('textbox'), 1, null)
 .forTargets(app.getElementById('status'))
 .setText('Cannot be empty');

  //add the handlers to the submit button
  app.getElementById('submit')
  .addClickHandler(serverHandler)
  .addClickHandler(myserverHandler)
  .addClickHandler(clientHandler);

 //add table to UI
 app.add(flex);
 //show app in the current spreadsheet
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 spreadsheet.show(app);
}

//check to see if textbox value is 'Fred'. If not display error

function myCheck(e) {
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 if (e.parameter.textbox != "Fred")
  var errorLabel = app.createLabel("Incorrect Value");
 app.add(errorLabel);

 return app;
}

//If all validation passes then display message

function submit(e) {
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 app.getElementById('status').setText('Server handler fired');
 return app;
}
```

I have attempted to use a serverhandler to check the textbox value but a clienthandler would be better. How do I write a custom client handler to check the textbox value for 'Fred'? Also, how do I prevent the serverhandler firing before all my validation conditions are met?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the UiApp service was deprecated. [UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605042/1595451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simpler than your code, one server handler is enough with a single validation on "Fred" and a ClientHandler using `validateNotMatches`.

Code below.

```
function myValid() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var textBox = app.createTextBox().setName('textbox').setId('textbox');
  var btn = app.createButton('Submit');
  var label = app.createLabel().setId('status');
  var flex = app.createFlexTable()
  .setWidget(0, 0, textBox)
  .setWidget(0, 1, btn)
  .setWidget(0, 2, label);
  var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('submit')
  .validateMatches(textBox, 'Fred')
  .addCallbackElement(flex);
  var clientHandler = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(textBox, 'Fred').forTargets(label).setText('Missing or invalid value');
  btn.addClickHandler(serverHandler).addClickHandler(clientHandler);
  app.add(flex);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}

function submit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('status').setText('Server handler fired');
  return app;
}
```

This code accepts any answer "containing" Fred, if you want it to reject anything but "Fred" alone just add a validation on the textBox length == 4 (`validateLength,textBox,4,4`), I wasn't sure what you really wanted...

---

**Edit :** Thanks for accepting, this edit just to mention there is also another approach that might interest you using `btn.setEnabled()` and a `KeyUpHandler`, code below... the choice is yours ;-)

```
function myValid() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var textBox = app.createTextBox().setName('textbox').setId('textbox');
  var btn = app.createButton('Submit').setEnabled(false);
  var label = app.createLabel().setId('status');
  var flex = app.createFlexTable()
  .setWidget(0, 0, textBox)
  .setWidget(0, 1, btn)
  .setWidget(0, 2, label);
  var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('submit')
  .validateMatches(textBox, 'Fred')
  .addCallbackElement(flex);
  btn.addClickHandler(serverHandler);
  var btnHandler = app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(textBox,'Fred').forTargets(btn).setEnabled(true);
  textBox.addKeyUpHandler(btnHandler);
  app.add(flex);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}

function submit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('status').setText('Server handler fired');
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, I thought I was over complicating things. Your answer clears things up - cheers!

Comment: Thanks again Serge. I've seen that approach elsewhere. Good to know and thanks for taking the time to supply a code example.